# Why does continuity mean that we can't break something?

Tags: general-topology

A homeomorphism is a bicontinuous bijection between two spaces, which intuitively means that it's a continuous deformation of the spaces, which means that we can't tear or break the space in the process.

A homotopy is a continuous map from one path to another, and this means we continuously deform the first path into the section path without breaking the path.

What I don't understand is how "continuous" implies that we can't break or tear something. What is the mathematical explanation for this?

Comment: Start by finding a mathematical definition of 'break'. To me, a map breaking something means finding a point $x$ such that even for points $y$ near $x$, $f(y)$ might be far from $f(x)$. The picture I have in my head is the map $\log(z)/i$ from the circle in the complex plane to the interval.

Comment: Because of the [blip function](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~hellm001/Publications/MathematicalPluralismSIA.pdf). Remember whether LEM applies to the continuum is not the question, does LEM apply to *a variable* ranging over the continuum? Colloquially - do we know exactly where it is?

Comment: Note that a continuous mapping maps a connected set to a connected set. So in this set nothing is broken (become disconnnected). \

Comment: Let there be a break at x.  That means that intuitively means f (x) to f (y) jumps a large distance while x and y are right next to each other.  In math terms, that means there is a distance epsilon, such that in every neighborhood of x, there is a point y such that d (f (x),f (y)) > epsilon.  This contradicts the math definition of continuous that says for *any* epsilon there is a neighborhood of x such that d (f (x)f (y)) < epsilon for all y in the neighborhood.

Comment: Any *positive* epsilon.  Distances are positive real values, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk in metric spaces, since we have an easy definition of continuity and a well-developed intuition about how things work there.

Continuous means the map can't "jump".  If you zoom in on a small patch of inputs you get a small patch of outputs.  If you zoom in further, you get a smaller patch of outputs.  In fact, if this is a continuous function, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that if we only look at a patch of inputs that is at most $\delta$ wide, the output is at most $\varepsilon$ wide.

A tear or jump would require that we *can't* make the output patch as small as we want.  For inputs at the jump, the output would have to include two patches that are separated by a positive distance.  For $\varepsilon$s smaller than that positive distance, the epsilon-delta definition of continuity has a problem.  I.e., this function isn't continuous.

You can say the same things in topology without a metric, but it can be abstract enough to not be convincing.  "Zooming in further" is replaced with replacing a (-n open) neighborhood of interest with a "smaller" neighborhood contained in the first one.  The same sorts of words apply as above.  However, you may find that your topological space doesn't have enough open sets to distinguish points.  (See the [Kolmogorov space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space) property.)  A point function can be "sloppy" about which of several indistinguishable points it maps an input point.  But this is why we don't just use bijective functions -- we use bicontinuous functions: not only do the points get mapped, but each element of one topology is mapped to an element of the other topology.  Entire open sets are mapped to entire open sets.  If you rip/tear/break an open set via the map, how does it remain open?  (This really is the same as the argument above about metric spaces.  I'm attempting to keep the abstraction under control.  I may not have entirely succeeded.  It's rather likely that the approximation above hides subtle errors.)

Comment: Okay, so do you think you could help me use this idea of a continuous deformation to understand why if I deform a loop centred at the origin into a point that isn't the origin, I have to cross the origin at some point? I know that it's because I can't break the loop, but I don't know how to express that rigorously.

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey : ... because there is a homotopy of the deformation where every point moves at uniform velocity along the straight line connecting its initial to final point.  Since there is at least one such line segment passing through the origin, at least one point passed through the origin in the original deformation.

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey : Alternatively...  At time $0$, the loop encircles the origin.  At time $1$, the loop has contracted to a point and does not encircle the origin.  There is therefore a last time, $t$, at which the origin goes from being encircled to not being encircled.  What must have happened at time $t$?

Comment: Just because there is a homotopy where every point moves at uniform velocity along the straight line connecting its initial point to its final point, how do we know there isn't some other homotopy that doesn't cause a point to pass through the origin?

Comment: Because homotopies are bijections of path components?  I'm trying to see how its possible to not see this thing you have just asked about.  Do you have this picture in your head:  There are two copies of the plane, labelled "$0$" and "$1$", with a volume between them.  On the plane $0$ is a loop around the origin.  On the plane $1$ is a point.  Between the two planes is a cone formed of line segments from each point of the initial loop to the point.  If you *stop* there, you might believe that its possible for the infinite jungle of line segments to part around the point at the origin.  ...

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey  ...  But, every slice parallel to the planes is another loop (connected object) and the deformation necessarily takes an open interval across one set of line segments through an infinite family of open intervals across the same set of line segments.  That is, every slice contains a smaller copy of the initial loop.  There is no "parting of the segments" to avoid any point.  This is one topological realization of the homotopy.  ...

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey : ... Now "rubber-sheet" deform it in all possible ways and you get all the homotopies, but any one of them is as good as any other under homeomorphism equivalence.  (I.e., the collection of homeomorphisms form a group acting on these various realizations of the homotopy preserving its properties).

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey : If you're still not getting it, it's time to talk to someone face-to-face.  This is an unavoidable geometric fact and the two of you will probably have to sketch many diagrams at each other.  (In fact, if you're not already staring at lots of little diagrams trying to show yourself what you mean, you're doing it wrong.  This is a 2-dimensional setting and the homotopies are only 3 dimensional objects.  You can actually draw what you think might be happening.)